# ¿Crear boton con RaisedButton?

Tags: flutter, dart

Estoy tratando de hacer este tipo de boton, pero cuando trato de hacerlo me lo coloca centrado.
En el codigo estoy usando dentro del expanded un RaisedButto.
Soy nuevo en Flutter.

[image: Alguien me puede ayudar]

```
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
        child: RaisedButton.icon(
      onPressed: () {
        print('123');
      },
      icon: Image.asset(
        'assets/icons/login/facebook.png',
        height: 20,
      ),
      label: Text(
        'Iniciar Sesión con facebook',
        style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.white),
      ),
      color: Colors.indigo[600],
    ))
  ],
);
```

Este es mi codigo

Comment: has probado aplicando la propiedad `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start` en el `Row`?

Comment: Hola, si tambien habia usado eso, ahi lo coloca al inicio, pero no me ocupa todo el ancho, sino solo lo que ocupa en si el texto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tendrías que revisar el widget `RaisedButton` con el `named` constructor `icon`, lo más seguro es que tenga un alineado al centro.

Puedes hacerlo con un `RaisedButton` solo también :

```dart
Row(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: RaisedButton(
                color: Colors.indigo[600],
                onPressed: () {
                  print('123');
                },
                child: Row(
                  children: [
                    Image.asset(
                      'assets/icons/login/facebook.png',
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(width: 10),
                    Text(
                      'Iniciar Sesión con facebook',
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
```

Comment: Gracias, al parecer esto fue mi solucion.

Answer (score 1):

La clase [RaisedButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RaisedButton-class.html) esta obsoleta en su lugar usa `ElevatedButton` que también tiene un constructor nombrado para agregarle un ícono.

```
    ElevatedButton.icon(
            onPressed: () {},
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              primary: Colors.white,
              shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                  Radius.circular(12),
                ),
                side: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
              ),
            ),
            icon: Image.asset(
              'assets/icons/login/google.png',
              height: 20,
            ),
            label: Text(
              'Iniciar Sesión con Google',
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
            ),
          ),
```